# get the username of the user who called script with sudo

Tags: command-line, bash

How do I get the username from within a script that was called with sudo?  In other words, I don't want `root` but the actual username.

**echo_user.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo whoami
```

Calling the script from user **pikachu**, I would expect it to print **pikiachu** and not **root**.

```
sudo ./echo_user.sh
```

There are lots of post from around 7 to 12 years ago with this exact question.  None of them seem to work on Ubuntu 22.x.  I'm simply trying to get the name of the user that called a script with sudo. Most of the old examples reference `SUDO_USER` but the only way I've been able to get it to work is by running `sh -c 'echo $SUDO_USER'`. echoing SUDO_USER from a script shows it's undefined.

Comment: it should be defined in a script, that's weird. Works for me in 20.04 WSL, and I don't know that anything has changed before 22.04/22.10

Comment: what were you doing in your script that was different from the answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$SUDO_USER"
```